# Date format changed in django forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am using django forms but date is not showing in specific format.

forms.py

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    receive_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control ','readonly':True }),
                                input_formats=DATE_INPUT_FORMATS, 
                                initial=date.today())

    class Meta:
      model = Mymodel
      fields = "__all__"
```

When i load or reload the page date format is look like

[image]

after when i clicked on date format will change, but it should not be change. it look like this

[image]

in Html file, simply i used

```
 {{forms.as_table}}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: i think, you need set date format inside your js calendar.

Answer (score 1):

The date format for client side widgets cannot be set server side. For the native browser datepicker, the date format is determined by the operating system's locale. If you use a javascript plugin for date picker, you can typically customize the date format with javascript.